# React Router (v4) Navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, materialize

***I am using v4 of react-router-dom***

I need to access `this.props.match` in my nav bar component so I can set the active class. I'm using react-materialize. In the `<NavItem>` tag, I want to add `className={this.props.match ? 'active' : ''}`. However, I can't seem to access the match. Props is an empty object every time when I print it in the console.

My Nav.js

```
<Navbar brand='Fuzic' href="/" className="orange darken-3" right>
  <NavItem className={this.match ? 'active' : ''} href="/devices">Devices</NavItem>
  <NavItem><Link to="/devices">Media</Link></NavItem>
  <NavItem><Link to="/devices">Alarms</Link></NavItem>
  <NavItem><Link to="/devices">Interrupts</Link></NavItem>
  <NavItem><Link to="/auth">Admin</Link></NavItem>
</Navbar>
```

My App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Nav/>
    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
        <PropsRoute exact path="/" component={Auth}/>
        <PropsRoute exact path="/devices" component={Devices} devices={this.state.devices} setCurrentDevice={this.setCurrentDevice} />
        <PropsRoute path="/devices/:deviceId" component={Detail} currentDevice={this.state.currentDevice} />
        <PropsRoute path="/auth" component={Auth}/>
        <PropsRoute component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

helper.js - combines props passed by me & props passed from react-router

```
// Exerp From:  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105
export const renderMergedProps = (component, ...rest) => {
  const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...rest);
  return (
    React.createElement(component, finalProps)
  );
}

export const PropsRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
      return renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest);
    }}/>
  );
}
```

Most of the documentation and articles online are for v2&3. The docs for v4 don't go into detail on how to handle this. Many people nested a route for their app. However, when I do that, I get a stack overflow in the console with a print of the frames.

How do I fix this so I can get access to match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your Nav component, try using react router's `<NavLink>` instead of `<Link>`.

`<NavLink>` is a special version of the `<Link>` that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

`<NavLink>` has **activeClassName** and **activeStyle** properties that you can use them to apply style to your active navigation item.

For example a basic navigation would be like this:

```
<nav>
    <NavLink activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/foo">Foo</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/bar">Bar Group</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/another-foo">Another Foo</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/another-bar">Another Bar</NavLink>
</nav>
```

Where **activeStyle** represents the style to apply to the element when it is active.

And below the same example via **activeClassName**:

```
<nav>
    <NavLink activeClassName="selected" to="/foo">Foo</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeClassName="selected" to="/bar">Bar Group</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeClassName="selected" to="/another-foo">Another Foo</NavLink>
    <NavLink activeClassName="selected" to="/another-bar">Another Bar</NavLink>
</nav>
```

**activeClassName** is the class to give the element when it is active. For this example I choose it to be `selected`. By default in react-router v4 given class for the active state is `active`.

Find more about `<NavLink>` on react-router v4 [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeStyle-object)

Comment: The problem that I'm having is integrating it with Materialize-CSS. When I use Materialize-CSS's `Navbar` component with the React-router-dom's Nav Link, I loose Matererialize's style because `NavLink` wants a vertical, white list. When I use Materialize-CSS `NavItem`, I get the right style, but loose access to setting the active class.

Comment: Can you check that if you really able to pass any props successfully to Nav.js component?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I didn't see it until just now. When I `console.log` at the top of my render function `this.props`, it prints `Object {children: undefined}`. So I think it has access to props, but there's nothing in there.

Comment: @SeyhanHuseyin When I am using `<NavLink>` menu **`/` menu** it's always keep active not change the class why ?? 
I was trying by `activeClassName="selected"` the same Problem keep `selected` class always not change another all there menu is ok...

Comment: @MDAshik
Your link to `/` is always active because every location begins with `/`. If you only want that link to be active when the pathname is `/`, then you should use the `exact` property.

For examle: 

`<NavLink exact to="/">test</NavLink>`

Check that section on the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool) for more info.

Comment: Ya, I already got it . I solved it by adding `exact="true"` Thanks for your reply .

Answer (score 2):

For those who are working with react-bootstrap v4 (using 1.0.0-beta.5 currently) and react-router-dom v4 (4.3.1) just use "as" prop from Nav.Link, here is full example:

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

<Navbar>
  {/* "Link" in brand component since just redirect is needed */}
  <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to='/'>Brand link</Navbar.Brand>
  <Nav>
    {/* "NavLink" here since "active" class styling is needed */}
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/' exact>Home</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/another'>Another</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/onemore'>One More</Nav.Link>
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

Here is working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/3qm35w97kq

Comment: I have this setup in a project I'm working on, but trying to use dynamic :Id for certain pages. The dynamic route is not working (e.g. the Nav.Link as={NavLink} renders exactly 'host/:userId/page' instead of dynamic 'host/{uid}/page').  Can you explain how to implement this functionality using Nav.Link please?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implement it, it works with
`"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"`
`"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5"`

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavBar, Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

const NavBar = ({location}) => (
    <NavBar>
        <Nav>
            <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/artists" to="/artists" active={location.pathname === '/artists'}>Artists</NavItem>
            <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/stages" to="/stages" active={location.pathname === '/stages'}>Stages</NavItem>
        </Nav>
    <NavBar>
// ...
```

Where `location` is the native property of a `Route`: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Just noticed that you're using `react-materialize` so my answer is probably not applicable to your question.

Answer (score 1):

"react": "^16.9.0" and "reactstrap": "^8.0.1"

```
import { NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarBrand} from "reactstrap";

 <NavLink 
  className="navbar-brand"
  activeClassName="active"
  tag={NavbarBrand}
  to='/'
  >
  My App
  </NavLink>
```